# HP 1020 won't print, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing

My HP 1020 printer doesn't print. I just updated to Ubuntu 12.04. My printer worked just fine in my previous Ubuntu version. The printer appears in the system configuration, appears to be installed, has a green check mark, says `inactive - ready to print`, but I can't print anything, not even the test page. The system doesn't inform me of any errors either. The printing jobs are listed in the printing row, and then they disappear, as if they had been completed, only they are not. I tried printing PDFs, webpages, and it doesn't work. Help please!!

Answer (score 1):

The HPLIP version installed within 12.04 seems to be outdated.  View and follow instructions [here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html)

After installation via Terminal, success.  My older HP1020 LaserJet was found, prints perfectly, and an HP utility tool can be installed within systray.  The HP utility makes it easy to install other printers as well; my HP 1320n LaserJet installed as well.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Click on **System Settings**

2 - Click on **Printers**

3 - Right Click on your **HP 1020 Printer**

4 - Make sure that Enabled has a tick mark next to it

[image]